# Converting Unicode in Swift

Tags: string, swift, unicode, scalar

I currently have a string as follows which I received through an API call:

> \n\nIt\U2019s a great place to discover Berlin and a comfortable place
>   to come home to.

And I want to convert it into something like this which is more readable:

> It's a great place to discover Berlin and a comfortable place to come
>   home to.

I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444391/unicode-to-utf8-in-swift) post, but that's manually writing down every conversion, and there may be more of these unicode scalar characters introduced.

What I understand is `\u{2019}` is unicode scalar, but the format for this is `\U2019` and I'm quite confused. Are there any built in methods to do this conversion?

Comment: See this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31483262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29522097/224988) suggests using the NSString method [`stringByFoldingWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).

The Swift [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:SS) class has a concept called a "view" which lets you operate on the string under different encodings. It's pretty neat, and there are some views that might help you.

If you're dealing with strings in Swift, read [this excellent post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html) by Mike Ash. He discusses the idea of what a string really is with great detail and has some helpful hints for Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already splitting the string and can get the offending format separately:

```
func convertFormat(stringOrig: String) -> Character {
    let subString = String(stringOrig.characters.split("U").map({$0})[1])
    let scalarValue = Int(subString)
    let scalar = UnicodeScalar(scalarValue!)
    return Character(scalar)
}
```

This will convert the String `"\U2019"` to the Character represented by `"\u{2019}"`.